# Why won't my lines plot in R when using the points statement with an existing graph?

Tags: r, plot, graph

I'm working through a book, *The R Student Companion*, and in the first chapter I've run across a problem. I'm trying to plot a graph using R but the "points" statement isn't plotting my line onto the graph.

Here is what I've got going on. I'm defining some list variables and plotting them as so.

```
moose.density=c(.17,.23,.23,.26,.37,.41,.66,.80,1.11,1.30,1.37,1.41,1.73,2.49)
kill.rate=c(.37,.47,1.9,2.04,1.12,1.74,2.78,1.85,1.88,1.96,1.8,2.44,2.81,3.75)
plot(moose.density,kill.rate,type="p")
```

As a result, I get this graph:

[image: graph].

Then I add these values and use the "points" statement to plot the line.

```
m=2.5*(0:100)/100
a=3.37
b=0.47
k=b*m/(a+m)
points(m,k,type="p")
```

This is the expected graph from the book, but nothing changes on mine. Am I doing something wrong? Is the points statement depreciated? I followed the book line-by-line.

[image: graph]

I thought it might have something to do with my R installation on Manjaro, but tried it on a Windows machine and got the same result.

Comment: I think there is an issue with your code. Your `k` values end at approximately 0.20, whereas `kill.rate` begins at 0.37. So none of the `k` values appear on the plot because they are all below the existing minimum.

Comment: It is plotting off the edge of the plot - if you set `ylim  = c(0, 3.5)` in the first plot, they will appear

Comment: [Here is the page](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=2APSBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA24&ots=0WEL3uekem&dq=The%20R%20Student%20Companion%20moose%20kill&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q=The%20R%20Student%20Companion%20moose%20kill&f=false) from the book. You have defined `k` incorrectly. It should be `k = a * m / (b + m)`.

Comment: and it should be `points(m,k,type="l")` (not `type="p"`)

Comment: @neilfws You are absolutely correct. It's a problem with the book and the line isn't on the graph. But you show page 25 which appears to be correct, the error on the book is on page 12. Thank you.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, I thought so too, it's a line, not points that I want. This book looks to have a few errors.

Comment: @neilfws If you'll write in your comment as an answer I can mark it as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: @Colton76 Done! You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments discussion, it appears that the code in this book contains several errors on certain pages, but not others.

The most relevant error is that:

```
k = b * m / (a + m)
```

generates values that are too small to appear on the plot. It should be:

```
k = a * m / (b + m)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that someone has already solved one part of the problem. Next, you should change `points(m,k,type="p")` to `lines(m, k)`.

Comment: What's the difference between `points(m,k,type="l")` and `lines(m,k)`? They both plot the same line.

Comment: Ah, no difference. I saw that you originally had type = "p". I was only addressing a part of the code that I did think anyone address to help you get the line you needed.